# is it "I am not like someone" or "I am not as someone"?

Tags: word-choice, comparison

When referring to not being like a specific group of girls....

Would you say

> I'm just not **like** them.

Or would it be written as:

> I'm just not **as** them.

Comment: Well, just compare the sentences:  He is speaking as  president of .... (he is the president).  He is speaking like the president.  (he is not the president but sounds like him).  He works like a dog (he works hard but he isn't a dog). She works as a secretary (she is a secretary).  Hope that can help.

Comment: 'Is it' is an imprecise way to ask. The acceptability of 'He's not as other men' shows that the second version is grammatical (some might still prefer 'they' for 'them'), but it's a terrible mix of registers and very unidiomatic. The first version would be used by 98%+ of Anglophones.

Comment: I would say "I'm not like you" but I wouldn't say "I'm not as you", unless it was followed by a comparison: "I'm not as curious as you are".  The same applies to "them" and "they".

Comment: Can you please give some more information about why you're considering these two options, and which one you think is correct? This will help people write more helpful answers.

Comment: But you could say "I'm just not the same as them," and it might carry a meaning very similar to "I'm just not like them."

Answer (score 1):

> I'm just not as them.

I believe you're technically correct here, after all you can say.  "As [somebody], I do X, Y, etc."

But it overwhelmingly sounds like words are missing here because this is similar to a very common pattern "I'm just not as [ good, bad, other modifier ] as them."

So you should really stick with "I'm just not like them."

Answer (score 1):

The basic rule is that "like" is used when followed by just a noun, while "as" is used when followed by a phrase.

"I'm not like him." - Correct

"I don't do it as he does." - Correct

"I'm not as him." - Incorrect

Now here's the tricky part: Officially speaking, it is incorrect to use "like" with a phrase, such as "I don't do it like he does." However, most native speakers actually use this phrasing anyway, and to some people it might actually sound better than doing it the "right" way.

But getting back to the question, using "as" with just a noun is incorrect, regardless of whether it is formal or informal. It sounds very odd.

https://www.grammarly.com/handbook/grammar/adjectives-and-adverbs/26/misuse-of-like-and-as/